# simply checking of undefined and null using !obj

Tags: javascript

I know `undefined` is not `===` to `null` but how about `!` operator? If I have a code that do this checking,

`if (obj === undefined || obj === null)`

is it wise to just simplify it as

`if(!obj)`

Are they identical?

Comment: You can actually do a very simple testing to try out yourself

Comment: In general it's better to be explicit than rely on Javascript's truthy/falsy checks, which can cause hard to track bugs.

Comment: @Jayce444 No truer words have been spoken. I had a very hard to track bug TODAY that was a result of a zero value being falsy, when i only cared that it wasn't `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

No.

`!obj` is also true for falsy things like `0`.

While `obj === undefined || obj === null` is only true if `obj` is `null` or `undefined`.

`!obj` is true for any falsy value.

They are:

- `false` (not really 'falsy' per-se ...)
- `0`
- `""`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `!` operator in checking, if compares all `falsey` value

Below is the list of `falsey` value:

- false
- 0 and other forms of numeric zero like -0, 0.0 and 0x0 (credit to RBT for hex form)
- "", '' and `` - strings of length 0
- null
- undefined
- NaN
- document.all

In other words:

```js
let obj = '';

if(!obj) { console.log('opps, not undefined, still printing')}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not.

Any falsy value will pass the test: 0, -0, null, undefined, an empty string, false.